# Liferay 7 apply programmatically a template to a journalArticle

Tags: liferay

I would like to apply a `DDMTemplate` pro-grammatically to `JournalArticle`. This is my code:

```
String prevDDMTemplate = articleDisplay.getDDMTemplateKey();
articleDisplay.setDDMTemplateKey(MY_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE);
articleContent = articleDisplay.getContent();
System.out.println(articleContent);
articleTitle = articleDisplay.getTitle();
articleDisplay.setDDMTemplateKey(prevDDMTemplate);
```

My expectation is that `articleContent` view is related to `MY_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE` template. But it doesn't work, the result is the content with the original template.

I need this change of view to print and to send the content by email. Is another way to do it?